# How to set a longtable to fit in the page width?

Tags: tables, longtable

I have a longtable that doesn't want to fit in the widht of the page. I already tried some methods like \resizebox\textwidth and \setlength but nothing seems to work. Do you have any ideas of how to solve this? Since now, thank you for your attention.

[image: Here how the table is now]

```
\begin{longtable}{lllllll}

\multicolumn{7}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{CCCCCC}Questionário de avaliação de Usabilidade e UX em interfaces              multi-toque (UXUMEQ)}                                                               \\
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{CCCCCC}Nome:}            \\
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{CCCCCC}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}– Por favor, preencha o questionário abaixo para avaliar a sua experiência na interação com\\ o sistema multi-toque.  Sua resposta é importante e nos ajudará a propor melhorias por \\meio desta avaliação.\\  

\\ – Cada questão contém uma escala de 5 pontos, com duas afirmações, uma à \\ e uma à direita. Caso concorde totalmente com a afirmação à esquerda, assinale 1. \\Caso concorde totalmente com a afirmação à direita, assinale 5.\\  

\\ – Nas questões abaixo assinale apenas uma resposta por questão.\\            
\\ – Não há respostas certas ou erradas. O importante para nós é a sua opinião.\\  \\ 

– Caso considere que alguma questão não deveria ser assinalada, descreva no campo de \\descrição da questão o motivo.\end{tabular}} \\


\multicolumn{7}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{B2B2B2}USABILIDADE}                                                                          \\
\multicolumn{7}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{CCCCCC}Performance}                                                                          \\
\multicolumn{7}{l}{1.               Você considera que seu              desempenho na tarefa do sistema multi-toque foi bom ou ruim?}               \\
                     &                                 &                                 &                                 &                                 &                                 &                          \\
\multirow{-2}{*}{Muito ruim}                                                         & 1                               & 2                               & 3                               & 4                               & 5                               & \multirow{-2}{*}{Muito bom}                                                              \\
\multicolumn{7}{c}{Descreva os problemas de performance que você percebeu}                                                   \\
\multicolumn{7}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{CCCCCC}Facilidade de uso}                                                                \\
\multicolumn{7}{c}{2. Foi fácil utilizar o sistema multi-toque? Ou seja, você alcançou seu objetivo sem grandes dificuldades?}                                                               \\
                     &                                 &                                 &                                 &                                 &                                 &                          \\
\multirow{-2}{*}{Muito              difícil}                                                      & 1                               & 2                               & 3                               & 4                               & 5                               & \multirow{-2}{*}{Muito                fácil}                                                            \\
\multicolumn{7}{l}{Descreva                 as dificuldades que você percebeu ao usar a interface               multi-toque}                           \\

\end{longtable}
```

Comment: `texdoc longtable` section 5 has an example

Answer (score 1):

First of all, always provide fully but minimum working example that demonstrates your problem, including document class, preamble, and document body. I had to Guess what packages you have loaded.

Below's a working solution but there are two problems in your code:

- Don't try to break lines manually. Let LaTeX do that for you.
  In tables, this is achieved by `p{}`-type column, which form paragraphs and in rare situations allows for using `\newline` to insert a line break, manually.
- If you want a list, use corresponding environments, such as `itemize`, `enumerate`, etc. The package `enumitem` adds further options to format lists.

Also, I haven't figured out how blocks following *Performance* and *Facilidade de uso* should be formated. The code had awful lots of `\multicolumn`s, which merge 7 columns to produce a line of left aligned text. I think it's easier to define one column and add an inner `tabular` to split a cell if necessary but I might be wrong.

EDIT. `ragged2e` with `\RaggedRight` as well as `babel` improve typesetting texts. I had to guess your language. If it's incorrect, change the optional argument at `babel` from `[portuguese]` to something else.

Here's the table

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}
\begingroup
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{longtable}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}
    \rule{0pt}{12pt}%
    \cellcolor[HTML]{CCCCCC}%
        Questionário de avaliação de Usabilidade e UX em interfaces multi-toque (UXUMEQ) \\
    \cellcolor[HTML]{CCCCCC}%
        \RaggedRight%
        Nome:
        \begin{itemize}[label={--}]
            \item Por favor, preencha o questionário abaixo para avaliar a sua experiência na interação com o sistema multi-toque.  Sua resposta é importante e nos ajudará a propor melhorias por meio desta avaliação.
            \item Cada questão contém uma escala de 5 pontos, com duas afirmações, uma à e uma à direita. Caso concorde totalmente com a afirmação à esquerda, assinale 1. Caso concorde totalmente com a afirmação à direita, assinale 5.
            \item Nas questões abaixo assinale apenas uma resposta por questão.
            \item Não há respostas certas ou erradas. O importante para nós é a sua opinião.
            \item Caso considere que alguma questão não deveria ser assinalada, descreva no campo de descrição da questão o motivo.
        \rule[-6pt]{0pt}{6pt}
        \end{itemize} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{B2B2B2}USABILIDADE} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{CCCCCC}Performance} \\
    1. Você considera que seu desempenho na tarefa do sistema multi-toque foi bom ou ruim? \\
    \begin{tabular}{@{}*7{c}@{}}
        Muito ruim &   &   &   &   &   & Muito bom \\
                   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 &
    \end{tabular} \\
    Descreva os problemas de performance que você percebeu \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{CCCCCC} Facilidade de uso} \\
    2. Foi fácil utilizar o sistema multi-toque? Ou seja, você alcançou seu objetivo sem grandes dificuldades? \\
    \begin{tabular}{@{}*7{c}@{}}
        Muito difícil &   &   &   &   &   & Muito fácil \\
                      & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 &
    \end{tabular} \\
    Descreva as dificuldades que você percebeu ao usar a interface multi-toque \\
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]